# Display jinja2 on a web page

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am working on an assignment and just can't resolve the following issue. I have created a python file with jinja2 and the help of an html template. When running the .py file terminal, the output is picobello fine with all the html commands, however I cannot display the file in a web browser. Firefox asks me how to open the python file, whereas chrome only displays the root python code and not the output. How can I display the output? I also need to embed this output to my main html webpage.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need a server running python, which will serve the HTML file. Checkout Flask or Django. Browsers can't run Python directly, but they can render HTML files directly, however not with jinja.